# unable to load the helper class inside a module in zend frame work

Tags: zend-framework

hi  i am a newbie in zend frame work.. pls help mee
i am going through a registration module. and in that module there is separate helper file  called Tools for calculating age... date comparison etc 
while trying to create object of Users_View_Helper_Tools  in indexAction getting a fattal error of Users_View_Helper_Tools not found
how will will we autoload the helper files in the modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bootstrap:

```
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath(
    'Path/To/Where/Your/Helper/Is',
    'Path_To_Where_Your_Helper_Is'
);
```

In controller:

```
$this->_helper->myHelper();
```

The helper would look like this:

```
class Path_To_Where_Your_Helper_Is_MyHelper extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{   
    public function direct()
    {
        echo 'Hello';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a helper path, use addHelperPath(); the docs will help you:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.paths